# How to render fetched data in Hexo using custom tag plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, promise, fetch, hexo

I am building a markdown based online documentation using Hexo but I want to extend its capabilities by rendering network devices output commands.

To be more clear, instead of copy-pasting a command and its result in a codeblock I want to fetch the result using http before rendering the page.

I already coded the soft in charge of running the desired command and exposing its result in a web server.

All it does is sending a string containing the result. It's just text.

**All I want is render this result in the page using a Hexo tag plugin**.

I really am in a dev stage right now so I only use the default theme ("landscape"). Since I'm working on an old Arch Linux version (`4.19.8-arch1-1-ARCH`) I'm using Docker.

### The file structure inside the container:

```sh
.
|-- _config.yml
|-- package.json
|-- scaffolds
|   |-- draft.md
|   |-- page.md
|   `-- post.md
|-- scripts
|   `-- index.js
|-- source
|   `-- _posts
|       `-- hello-world.md
`-- themes
```

### The Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.11.2

WORKDIR /gtd

ADD . .

RUN npm install hexo-cli -g
RUN npm install hexo-server --save
RUN npm install node-fetch --save
RUN npm install

CMD ["hexo", "server"]
```

### The hello-world.md

```
{% cli_exporter "output" "show_version" "some_router" %}
```

### The custom plugin (scripts/index.js)

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

hexo.extend.tag.register("cli_exporter", (args) => {
        const hostname = "XX.YYY.ZZZ.WW:XXXX"
        let endpoint, module, target
        [endpoint, module, target] = args 

        const url = "http://" + hostname + '/' + endpoint
                + "?module=" + module + "&target=" + target

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                        return response.text()
                        .then(data => "<div>" + data + "</div>")
                        .catch(error => console.error(error))
                }
                return Promise.reject(new Error("response failed"))
        })
        .catch(error => Promise.reject(new Error(error.message)))
}, {async: true});
```

I really can't give you the real hostname since it's private software but it's really just plain text.

Let's say I want to render a `show version` result from a Cisco router. If I `console.log(data)` in the plugin I get the expected result. But it is not render in the generated website.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess my javascript is a little rusty. I solved this adding a return.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function request(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const text = await response.text()

        return text
}

hexo.extend.tag.register("cli_exporter", (args) => {
        const hostname = "XX.YYY.ZZZ.WW:XXXX"
        let endpoint, module, target
        [endpoint, module, target] = args 

        const url = "http://" + hostname + '/' + endpoint
                + "?module=" + module + "&target=" + target

        return request(url)
        .then(data => {
                return "<div>" + data + "</div>"
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
}, {async: true});
```